# Why does the devise sign_in fail when you change the user.email field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Given a controller:

```
def update
  .....
  user.save
  sign_in(:user, user)
```

What's happening is the user is having their email changed from lets say x@x.com to y@y.com... And then when I try to sign_in w devise, for some reason it's not working. It doesn't error but doesn't sign the user in. reason being current_user is not being set.

Any ideas why and solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the devise version I'm using doesn't let users change their email. It's strange because I redirect to the edit page so the params make it look like it changed, but in fact it does not. Make sure the emails are actually getting changed.